# Not processing multiplication inside the class

Tags: java

How can I fix the multiplication error?
The formula is inside the nested class Area1 and I can't get the total value or product given by the user

I've tried giving it a value like:

side1 = 0;

or

side1 = 1;

The answer is always equal to 0

```
public void getArea(){
    int area = side1 * side2;
    System.out.println("Area of square: " + area);
```

```
Area1 square = new Area1(side1,side2);
        square.getArea();
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Area1 {
    int side1;
    int side2;
    int height;
    int base;
    int width;
    int length;
Area1 (int side1,int side2,int height,int base, int width, int length){
    this.side1 = side1;
    this.side2 = side2;
    this.width = width;
    this.length = length;
}

    private Area1(int height, int base) {
        this.height = height;
        this.base = base;
    }
    
public void getArea(){
    int area = side1 * side2;
    System.out.println("Area of square: " + area);
}
public void getArea1(){
    int area2 = height * base / 2;
    System.out.println("Area of triangle: " + area2);
}
public void getArea2(){
    int area2 = width * length;
    System.out.println("Area of rectangle: " + area2);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int side1 = 0;
        int side2 = 0;
        int height;
        int base;
        int width;
        int length;
        System.out.println("-----FOR SQUARE-----");
        System.out.println("Please enter 1st side of square: ");
        side1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter 2nd side of square: ");
        side2 = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("-----FOR TRIANGLE-----");
        System.out.println("Please enter height of triangle: ");
        height = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter base of triangle: ");
        base = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("-----FOR RECTANGLE-----");
        System.out.println("Please enter width of rectangle: ");
        width = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter length of rectangle: ");
        length = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("=====THE RESULTS ARE=====");
        Area1 square = new Area1(side1,side2);
        square.getArea();
        Area1 triangle = new Area1(height, base);
        triangle.getArea1();
        Area1 rectangle = new Area1(width,length);
        rectangle.getArea2();
}  
}
```

Comment: So one of your sides must be zero. If you are using primitive values, then you might not initialized one of them, then they would become zero by default. We could use more code to find the bug

Comment: @Beri i added the whole code to the post just now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:

You are setting only two properties (you are using single constructor only):

```
   private Area1(int height, int base) {
     this.height = height;
     this.base = base;
   }
```

So you are setting only two fields.
And in our compute methods you are using other fields, that are not set. And because they are primitive types, they are set to zero. Youn need to use other full arg constructor.

This is a great candidate for object oriented programming:

```
abstract class Figure {
    abstract void getArea();
}

public class Square extends Figure {
    private final int side1;
    private final int side2;

    Square(int side1, int side2) {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
    }

    @Override
    void getArea() {
        int area = side1 * side2;
        System.out.println("Area of square: " + area);
    }
}
```

public class Triangle extends Figure {
private final int base;
private final int height;

```
   Triangle(int base, int height) {
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    void getArea() {
        int area2 = height * base / 2;
        System.out.println("Area of triangle: " + area2);
    }
}
```

And now you can compute:

```
    System.out.println("=====THE RESULTS ARE=====");
    Figure square = new Square(side1, side2);
    square.getArea();
    Figure triangle = new Triangle(height, base);
    triangle.getArea();
```

With this approach you will not have to multiple variables if new figure will be added. You will not have to struggle with large constructor. Lastly: you are using only few fields for each figure, rest is useless.

Comment: it won't let me get the answer when i added the user input codes from square

//Square(int,int) has private access to Square)

Comment: You can change the constructor to package or public. If you are using those classes outside of the package, then make their scope public. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, in the constructor you assign the values only for height and base.

```
private Area1(int height, int base) {
    this.height = height;
    this.base = base;
}
```

When you call this,

```
Area1 square = new Area1(side1,side2);
square.getArea();
```

the `getArea()` method looks for the variables `side1` and `side2`. But you have set the variables `height` and `base` only. So, the variables `side1` and `side2` have the value `0` by default.

Possible solution:
You should probably initialize the objects with the other constructor method that you already have, that uses all the variables, like

```
Area1 square = new Area1(side1,side2,0,0,0,0);
square.getArea();
Area1 triangle = new Area1(0, 0, height, base, 0, 0);
triangle.getArea1();
Area1 rectangle = new Area1(0,0,0,0,width,length);
rectangle.getArea2();
```

Comment: It works on both square and rectangle thanks but can you explain why do i need to put the 0 values inside new Area1? 

Sorry im a student and still new to programming

Comment: Is it not working for `triangle` ? 

You should pass some value in each argument. Why not 0. Can't leave them blank. You can pass any other value as well.
For `square` we are not going to use `getArea1()` or `getArea2()` methods. If we call those, it will print area as `0`. Similarly, for other 2 shapes.

Also, you can initialise everything in a single variable as well. But it depends on your use case. Example: `Area1 all = new Area1(side1,side2,height,base,width,length);` and use it like, 
`all.getArea();` for square,
`all.getArea1();` for triangle,
`all. getArea2();` for rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

You made mistake in your parameterize constructor as you assign side1 and side2 value to this.height = height; this.base = base; and you trying to multiply side1 and side2 which has default value only.

```
private Area1(int side1, int side2) {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
    }
```